# Swift triple arrow symbol

Tags: swift

I saw in [swift 4.0 source code](https://github.com/Ramotion/preview-transition/blob/9bae1297b2f7a36bb81359bcd3afd9423721fd13/PreviewTransition/DetailViewController/PTDetailViewController.swift#L101) with '>>>-' symbol, I have search for the reference of this symbol in documents i couldn't find it, Xcode throws me error `Use of unresolved operator '>>>-'`

Can someone explain what is this symbol means & why?

thanks

Comment: That is not an operator from the Swift standard library. Most probably, it is defined in that project or some framework that it depends on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That operator is not provided by Swift. It is a custom operator defined by the author of that library.

You can find the definition in another [file](https://github.com/Ramotion/preview-transition/blob/9bae1297b2f7a36bb81359bcd3afd9423721fd13/PreviewTransition/TableViewController/Halpers/ConstraintsHalper.swift):

```
precedencegroup constOp {
    associativity: left
    higherThan: AssignmentPrecedence
}

infix operator >>>-: constOp

@discardableResult
func >>>- <T: UIView>(left: (T, T), block: (inout ConstraintInfo) -> Void) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
    var info = ConstraintInfo()
    block(&info)
    info.secondAttribute = info.secondAttribute == .notAnAttribute ? info.attribute : info.secondAttribute

    let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: left.1,
                                        attribute: info.attribute,
                                        relatedBy: info.relation,
                                        toItem: left.0,
                                        attribute: info.secondAttribute,
                                        multiplier: 1,
                                        constant: info.constant)
    constraint.identifier = info.identifier
    left.0.addConstraint(constraint)
    return constraint
}
```

And because the function `func >>>- <T: UIView>(left: (T, T), block: (inout ConstraintInfo) -> Void) -> NSLayoutConstraint` is not declared public, you cannot use it outside of its declaring module.

Comment: Thanks a lot, is their any resources that i can learn more about this custom operator definitions.

Comment: Ok its just a plain function name is '>>>-', I understand now.

Comment: Just look that up on Google. I've found this: http://www.codingexplorer.com/custom-operators-swift/ @WimalWeerawansa It's more than a function. You also need to write the declaration of it to say whether it is infix, postfix or prefix. You can also optionally include a `precedencegroup`.